# .sql file in Docker Postgres Container not automatically executed

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a `.sql` file created from a `pg_dump` command that I would like to have automatically inserted into my PostgreSQL instance in my Docker container. I mount my `.sql` file into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`directory using volume. My Docker YML file looks like the following:

```
postgres: 
 environment: 
  - POSTGRES_USER=user
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw
  - POSTGRES_DB=db
 volumes:
  - ./out.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/out.sql
 image: "postgres:9.6"
```

Since the sql file has been mounted into `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` I expect it to automatically run and insert my data when I run `docker-compose -f myyml.yml up -d`. It does not execute. However, when I run bash in my container I do see my `.sql` file. Also, I can manually run the file with a command similar to `psql -U user -a -f out.sql`. Why is it not automatically running when I run docker-compose?

Answer (score 3):

So after a lot of trial and error, I realized that I needed to remove all images and containers and restart. I ran a `docker-compose myyml.yml down` and reran and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can add `command` in docker compose, and as following `psql -U user -a -f out.sql`

```
postgres: 
 environment: 
  - POSTGRES_USER=user
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw
  - POSTGRES_DB=db
 volumes:
  - ./out.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/out.sql
 image: "postgres:9.6"
 command: bash -c "psql -U user -a -f out.sql"
```

note : if with use command `bash -c` is not work, remove it

Comment: I am getting the error ```postgres_1  | psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
postgres_1  |  Is the server running locally and accepting
postgres_1  |  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: @user3776598 please re-create/re-build image, you can use command ``sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate service``. than try again, in my tested in successful,... tell me if you get error again... i hope can help you